# Downloaded 64 bit, no ISO?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, files, downloads, iso

I've recently installed the newest download, and I can't find the ISO anywhere to put onto USB (in my case, a Hard Drive).

Here's what the download file looks like;

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The whole file that you downloaded is the Ubuntu iso file. What you are seeing in your screenshot is what the contents of the iso file look like after the iso file has been mounted.

Comment: When I try to install Ubuntu, it installs onto my C: drive not my E:, how can I change that?

Comment: Try running **wubi.exe** which is shown in your  screen shot

Comment: I have, I then get to this screen, click, help me boot from CD, and then it proceeds to install onto C: :\

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso). If it doesn't work,you might be opening with WinZIP or some other software that is showing the bulk of the image. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this the ISO? http://gyazo.com/67529623ea9ff65b469ddce598b13f46